# unable to install ntpdate on centos

Tags: ntp, ntpdate

I'm running centos 6, unable to get ntpdate working, what's wrong?

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
bash: ntpdate: command not found
x yum install ntpdate
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nwresd.org
 * epel: epel.mirror.freedomvoice.com
 * extras: mirrors.sonic.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.webnx.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.ndchost.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ntpdate.x86_64 0:4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: openntpd-3.9p1-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts ntpdate
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: openntpd conflicts with ntpdate-4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `openntpd` and `ntpdate` are two completely different utilities/programs and have been shown to have conflicts because they take different approaches to synchronizing the time for a host.  It looks like the CentOS/RHEL package maintainers have decided that the differences are serious enough to mark them as mutually exclusive and avoid the potential problems having both installed can lead to - you can have one or the other but not both.

Hence, you have a couple of options, you can uninstall `openntpd` and then install `ntpdate` (just use `yum remove` to remove it) or you can leave things as-is and use `openntpd` to do a [manual update](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenNTPD#Error_adjusting_time):

```
ntpd -s -d
```